# Circumellipse of elongated parallelogram

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, triangle-centres

I am looking for the parameters/equation of an ellipse that would pass through all the vertices of an elongated parallelogram.

The ellispe has 5 free parameters: center $(x_0,y_0)$, major and minor axes $a$ and $b$ as well as an orientation $\theta$. The elongated parallelogram is fully defined by 3 vectors (6 parameters), therefore over-determining the system. However, there should be an analytical (and unique) solution to this problem !

Here is a visual help to understand my question (here, for simplicity, the three vectors are set at a 120° angle from each other):

[image: Ellipse around an elongated parallelogram]

Obviously, in some out-of-scope cases one might obtain a hyperbola instead of an ellipse. I would be very interested in a solution, even if one needs stronger assumptions (like the 120° angle between the vectors).

P.S.: The problem would probably be similar to finding the circumellipse of a triangle (orange), whose center (origin of the vectors) unfortunately doesn't match the basic Kimberling centers (incenter/centroid/etc.). The closest match I found is the [Excentral-Hexyl Ellipse](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Excentral-HexylEllipse.html), but the center is not the right one.

**Edit:** The name elongated parallelogram actually refers to a [centroid hexagon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentroidHexagon.html).

Comment: I don't understand how the hexagon on the figure can be called "elongated parallelogram" ...

Comment: Plug the coordinates of any $5$ vertices into the generic equation of a conic and compute the coefficients.

Comment: What is an *elongated parallelogram*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I used the term from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogon#Two_polygonal_types however, it looks like a better name would be "centroid hexagon" https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentroidHexagon.html
I am unaware of any more general/accurate description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opposite vertices of the hexagon have the same midpoint $O$, which is also the centre of the ellipse. Translate all vertices so that $O=(0,0)$: the equation of the ellipse simplifies then to
$$
Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2=1.
$$

Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be any three non-opposite vertices of the hexagon (you can take for instance three consecutive vertices, or three alternate vertices as in your figure). Plugging the coordinates of those points into the above equation we can find $A,B,C$ (please check the result):
$$
A={x_P y_P (y_Q^2 - y_R^2) + x_Q y_Q (y_R^2-y_P^2 )+x_R y_R(y_P^2 - y_Q^2)
\over( x_P y_Q-x_Q y_P )(x_Q y_R - x_R y_Q )(x_P y_R-x_R y_P )}\\
B={1\over2}{x_R^2 (y_Q^2-y_P^2) + x_Q^2 (y_P^2 - y_R^2) + x_P^2 (y_R^2-y_Q^2 )
\over ( x_P y_Q-x_Q y_P )(x_Q y_R - x_R y_Q )(x_P y_R-x_R y_P )} \\
C={x_P y_P (x_Q^2 - x_R^2) + x_Q y_Q (x_R^2-x_P^2 )+x_R y_R(x_P^2 - x_Q^2)
\over( x_P y_Q-x_Q y_P )(x_Q y_R - x_R y_Q )(x_P y_R-x_R y_P )}
$$
Finally, the axes can be found from eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix
$m=\pmatrix{A & B \\ B & C}$: eigenvalues are $1/a^2$ and $1/b^2$, while eigenvectors give the directions of the axes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check it out. However, do you have any idea "where" the parameters' redundancy occurs? There are effectively only 5 free parameters, right?

Comment: Here is a piece of mathematica code that validates your answer (just the result, not the reasoning). Thanks again.

`(*3 arbitrary points in the plane*)
P = {xp, yp}; Q = {xq, yq}; R = {xr, yr}; 
(*Ellipse equation to be solved*)
ellipse[x_, y_] := (a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2 == 1) 
(*Solving the system for the parameters a,b,c*)
sol = Solve[MapApply[ellipse[##] &, {P, Q, R}], {a, b, c}];
(*Clean-up of the solution*)
sol = Flatten@Assuming[{P, Q, R} \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify@%]`

Comment: @Mammouth There is no redundancy: you know three independent points and the centre (which is worth 2 parameters), the other points don't matter.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if this center corresponds do a known Kimberling center?

Comment: @Mammouth The centre of the ellipse could be anywhere, it isn't related to the triangle.

Comment: @Mammouth In other words: you have $6$ points but their positions are not independent, because $3$ of them are the reflexions of the other $3$ about the same centre. Hence they are equivalent to having $3$ points and the centre of symmetry, i.e. $5$ parameters.

Comment: I logged in to delete my comment as I realized my question was absurd, sorry :)
What I fail to understand is that those 3 points are coordinates in the plane that each require 2 parameters.

Comment: @Mammouth A point on the ellipse gives a single relation among the coefficients in the general equation of a conic, obtained plugging the coordinates of the point into that equation. The centre of the conic, on the other hand, gives two relations, because both coordinates of the centre [can be expressed as functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse) of said coefficients.